# Получить данные из двух таблиц Symfony

Tags: symfony, php, mysql

Я изучаю фреймворк Симфони. У меня есть таблица `orders`, из которой я получаю все данные таким образом:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$this->items = OrdersPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Как получить данные из одной таблицы, я разобрался, но есть еще одна таблица "orders_complete", которую я хочу присоединить. В общем, я хочу получить данные из двух таблиц.

Как выполнить такой запрос?

```
SELECT * FROM orders, orders_complete
WHERE orders.id=orders_complete.id
```

Answer (score 1):

[[@akasergej](/users/26298/akasergej)](/users/26298/akasergej), там же доктрина/пропель, откуда вообще такой синтаксис растет? Symfony построена на декларативном подходе, в сущностях объявляются связи, а потом сущности запрашиваются через репозитории с автоматическим подтягиванием связей. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: перевод документации
https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что в таблице `orders_complete` вы держите завершенные заказы и хотите таким образом выбрать из таблицы `order` все завершенные:

1. Нативный SQl: `SELECT * FROM order WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM orders_complete);`
2. QueryBuilder:

```
$orderCompleteBuilder = $this->orderCompleteRepository->createQueryBuilder('oc')
       ->select('oc');

$orderBuilder = $this->orderRepository->createQueryBuilder('o');
$orderBuilder
       ->where(
           $orderBuilder->expr()->in('id', $orderCompleteBuilder->getQuery()->getDQL());
       )
       ->getQuery();

$result = $orderBuilder->getResult();
```